# In Genesis 36:5, the name of Aholibamah's son is in the ms twice but only rendered once in all the translations I have checked. Why?

Tags: genesis

When I put the name in a translator, it comes out "Yiddish Yeush."  Most translations just say "Yeush." There are also brackets around the first word of the name and parentheses around the second word of the name, which I don't understand. Any insight on any of this would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the received pronunciation is different from the received written text. When the Masorites wrote down the Masoretic text, the voweled Hebrew Bible, in order to include both, the unvoweled written text is written with the voweled spoken text found directly after it. The pronunciation is called the qere, and the written text is called the kethiv. The translation of the text almost always follows the qere, as the kethiv variance is often caused by small scribal errors.

The Hebrew text is as follows: "וְאָהֳלִֽיבָמָה֙ יָֽלְדָ֔ה אֶת־יעיש [יְע֥וּשׁ] וְאֶת־יַעְלָ֖ם וְאֶת־קֹ֑רַח אֵ֚לֶּה בְּנֵ֣י עֵשָׂ֔ו אֲשֶׁ֥ר יֻלְּדוּ־ל֖וֹ בְּאֶ֥רֶץ כְּנָֽעַן׃" We are concerned with "[יעיש [יְע֥וּשׁ". The brackets indicate that the word יְע֥וּשׁ is the qere of the kethiv יעיש (another way to tell is by noticing that the kethiv is unvoweled). Thus, when you copied the text into a translator, you copied both the kethiv and the qere, so the translator translated both separately not knowing that they were the same word.

Comment: Thank you.  That explains a lot.